# maintain the states of android application

Tags: android

I am developing an application on cab booking.There is a two applications one user side and another is driver side.

1.) When user will book the ride, driver will get the notification with user details like pickup location, drop location,and user name etc. and i am showing those details in map as well as in text on driver app screen. After showing those details if phone got switched off or application got closed or application got crashed, if i reopen the application how can i open the application with user details screen?

2.) After getting the request driver will accept that request and he will reach to user location, then the wait time will start's counting, in this case if phone got switched off or application got closed or application got crashed, if i reopen the application how can i open the application with waiting time counting screen?

3.) After getting the request, after wait time count ends, driver will start the ride, after starting the ride there will be a count of riding time and riding distance count will start's, in this case if phone got switched off or application got closed or application got crashed, if i reopen the application how can i open the application with ride time and ride distance count screen?

please let me know is there any solution or not. If any one know's help me on this. If any one not understand my question let me know.

Thank you....

Comment: If any one not understands my question, please let me know.....

Comment: you have to override the onDestroy function of the activty. Whenever your app crash or close unexpectedly you can save your desired data to memory or any another location. And whenever you re-open your app you can check some flag that is your app closed unexpectedly then load data

Comment: all these ride functionality i am maintaining in one fragment with different layouts. By the way i am using onDistroyView() in my fragment to unregiser BR for event listners

Comment: as per your comment @ Raj Sharma in onDistroyView(), i have to save data?  If i save the data like (wait time , ride time and distance), after re open the app these count's should resume's from their previous state, is it possible?

Comment: yes you can resume all the data. But you have to save the states of all the required variables. you can also take help of serialization.

Comment: Hi Raj As per your suggestion i have serached on google how to save data in onDestroy. but i have found many answer's like, The methods onDestroy() and onStop() might never be called before the activity is shut down. can you help on this?